# c# Switch font if not support

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

I tried using font "Malgun Gothic" to show Korean character, but sometimes this control show vietnamese, "Malgun Gothic" not support for vietnamese character.
- How to witch between "Malgun Gothic" and "Verdana" font, if not support.
- I see "Microsoft word" switch from "Malgun Gothic" to "Calibri" font, if not support character.

See this code:

```
this.lblTit.AutoSize = true;
this.lblTit.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Malgun Gothic", 15F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.World, ((byte)(129)));
this.lblTit.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 10);
this.lblTit.Name = "lblTit";
this.lblTit.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(46, 20);
this.lblTit.TabIndex = 1;
this.lblTit.Text = "Chọn";
```

=> I want 3 character "C", "h" and "n" show by "malgun Gothic" font , and character "ọ" show by "Verdana" font.

How to do that.

Comment: That's not possible. Winforms label can have only one font, one size and one style for the whole text. So you should use different labels if you want your behavior.  If you want to  go  hard way you should create your own derived Control and use GDI+ to manually control character drawing.

Comment: This mean Fallback font, how to set fallback font ?

Answer (score 0):

A label has one font; you can not combine it with another font. You have to either decide for one font that covers all the characters you need, or you have to use three labels, one for `"Ch"` one for `"ọ"` and one for `"n"`.

This would look like this (removed unnecessary lines):

```
this.lblTit1.AutoSize = true;
this.lblTit1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Malgun Gothic", 15F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.World, ((byte)(129)));
this.lblTit1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 10);
this.lblTit1.Text = "Ch";

this.lblTit2.AutoSize = true;
this.lblTit2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 15F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.World, ((byte)(129)));
this.lblTit2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(lblTit1.Location.X + lblTit1.Width, 10);
this.lblTit2.Text = "ọ";

this.lblTit3.AutoSize = true;
this.lblTit3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Malgun Gothic", 15F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.World, ((byte)(129)));
this.lblTit3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(lblTit2.Location.X + lblTit2.Width, 10);
this.lblTit3.Text = "n";
```

If your code is auto-generated, you wouldn't set the location like in the code sample; you would use the visual designer to align the labels.